# Do I need to recompile iphone app after modifying AdHoc distribution profile?

Tags: iphone, distribution, adhoc

Do I need to recompile, resign the application for AdHoc distribution and re-distribute it to all beta testers after I add a new device to the Adhoc distribution profile?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should be able to just add the devices, attach them to the provisioning profile, download the new .provision file and distribute that along with your zipped-up .app directory.

I'm only 99% sure of this, so test it with another device or one beta-tester before spamming everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create a new build with new certificate installed in xcode.